# Getting Hibernate version from Spring dependency management to configure plug-in in Gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, gradle

Is it possible to get the Hibernate version managed by [Spring Boot's dependency management](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#introduction) to configure a plug-in with that version?

I want to configure the [Hibernate plug-in](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement-enhancement-gradle) with the same version as Hibernate Core, to not have to update this version by hand every time.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:${hibernate.version}"
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                           unknown!
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'
```

But the only thing I get is this error message:

> Could not get unknown property 'hibernate' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Is there a way to get the Hibernate version from the Spring configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bold answer : not possible

Because the `buildscript` block is evaluated early and all dependencies here must be resolved first, they cannot depend on the future result of the `dependencyManagement` block evaluation.

Even if the `Dependency Management Plugin` offers [a nice way](https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#accessing-properties) to get the hibernate version

```
dependencyManagement.importedProperties['hibernate.version']
```